# react-countdown not handling time increments properly

Tags: reactjs, countdown

I'm using react-countdown to show a timer in my web-app. I have a method that can add 10 seconds to the timer, here's the code:

```
const [timerState, setTimerState] = useState({
    isPaused: false,
    isStopped: true,
    date: new Date(Date.now() + 100000),
  });

const addSeconds = () => {
    setTimerState({
        ...timerState,
        date: new Date(timerState.date.getTime() + 10000),
    })
}
```

Whenever I execute this method, exactly 10 seconds are added to the state, but in the renderer, it shows an increment of varying values (sometimes 8, sometimes 9 etc). Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Here's the code for the timer:

```
const [timerState, setTimerState] = useState({
    isPaused: false,
    isStopped: true,
    date: new Date(Date.now() + 300000),
});
let timerApi = undefined;

const setRef = (timer) => {
  if (timer) {
    timerApi = timer.getApi();
  }
};

const renderTime = (count) => {
    if (count < 10) {
      return `0${count}`;
    } else {
      return count;
    }
  };


const customRenderer = ({ hours, minutes, seconds, completed }) => {
    return (
      <div className={styles.time}>
        {hours > 0
          ? `${renderTime(hours)}:${renderTime(minutes)}:${renderTime(seconds)}`
          : `${renderTime(minutes)}:${renderTime(seconds)}`}
      </div>
    );
  };

return (
    <Countdown
      date={timerState.date}
      overtime={true}
      ref={setRef}
      autoStart={false}
      intervalDelay={0}
      renderer={customRenderer}
    />
)
```

Comment: Could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?